# Custom Post Type UI

Tags: custom-post-types

I'm using the plugin custom post type ui to create a post type says movie. Everything is ok. I create a movie and its viewable at

```
http://localhost/wordpress/movies/test/
```

however, when i go on

http://localhost/wordpress/movies/

I was expecting to see test as a movie in all the list of movies but nothing is displayed

Code generated by the plugin:

```
register_post_type('movies', array(
    'label' => 'Movies',
    'description' => '',
    'public' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_in_menu' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'rewrite' => array('slug' => ''),
    'query_var' => true,
    'supports' => array(
            'title','editor','excerpt','trackbacks',
            'custom-fields','comments','revisions','thumbnail','author',
            'page-attributes',),
    'taxonomies' => array('category','post_tag',),
    'labels' => array (
          'name' => 'Movies',
          'singular_name' => 'Movie',
          'menu_name' => 'Movies',
          'add_new' => 'Add Movie',
          'add_new_item' => 'Add New Movie',
          'edit' => 'Edit',
          'edit_item' => 'Edit Movie',
          'new_item' => 'New Movie',
          'view' => 'View Movie',
          'view_item' => 'View Movie',
          'search_items' => 'Search Movies',
          'not_found' => 'No Movies Found',
          'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Movies Found in Trash',
          'parent' => 'Parent Movie',
),) );
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the post type registration code?

Comment: ok, the code posted is the code generated by the plugin

Comment: `'slug' => ''` - why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add `has_archive` => 'movies' to the arguments array you pass to `register_post_type` and you should be fine, since by default it is set to false.

Comment: yes, this solution works. thanks. But still one problem, when I create a post from the new postype, and attach with it a category, when i go on the URL ..../category/<categoryname>

Comment: By default category archive only pulls regular posts and not custom ones, but thhe is a another question.

Comment: then I'll think I must create custom taxonomy then pulls these custom posts

Comment: Or simply edit your category archive to show your custom post type

Comment: I suppose i have to override this in category.php get_template_part( 'loop', 'category' );

Comment: like i said, that's another question.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the admin panel and under settings tab go to the permalinks tab and once you are in the permalinks page save changes and try again.
This is a hidden trick with wordpress. The cache gets cleared once you visit the permalinks page and save changes. I think this should work for you.

Comment: All you really have to do is just visit the page -- saving isn't even necessary.

Comment: Unfortunately, same problem, I've noticed that even when attaching a post of custom type with a category, say IT, even when go to .../category/it, it does not show up

Answer (score 0):

I see a number of issues with your code:

```
'rewrite' => array('slug' => ''),
```

you can't have a slug of `''` it doesn't work. There is no hack around in core to fix this, and there are good reasons regarding permalink clashes for this. I can only assume you're trying to make the custom post work like pages but it won't work this way. Change it to something else or simply make `rewrite` equal to `true`

```
'label' => 'Movies',
```

You've already defined the labels array, this is unnecessary.

Lastly, the category archive is by default only showing posts of type `post`. So your movies will not appear there.

To fix this, place this in your `functions.php`:

```
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'query_post_type');
function query_post_type($query) {
  if(is_category() || is_tag()) {
    $post_type = get_query_var('post_type');
    if($post_type)
        $post_type = $post_type;
    else
        $post_type = array('post','movies'); // replace cpt to your custom post type
    $query->set('post_type',$post_type);
    return $query;
    }
}
```

In future, indent your code correctly ( I had to fix it in your post, it was unreadable, and unreadable code is usually broken code too ), and [use a generator like this one for registering post types and taxonomies](http://themergency.com/generators/wordpress-custom-post-types/)